# Omelette cooked in oven or pan?

Tags: omelette

What differences are, besides speed, when cooking omelettes in oven versus in the frying pan?

I have traditionally always used pan but i see now some recipes recommend oven.

Comment: There are different types of omelettes, with different methods.  Can you narrow the focus of the question?

Comment: I have never heard of an omelette made in the oven. Mind = blown. Is it more like a frittata or something?

Comment: Ît was indeed made in the oven and it was a omelette.

Comment: Did the recipe call for it being made entirely in an oven? It's common to start them in a skillet and transfer them to an oven to set the eggs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because the recipe calls it an "omelette" doesn't make it one. An omelette starts and ends its cooking in a pan. If you finish it in the oven, it becomes a frittata. (There are a couple of historic differences, but let's just stick with that.) If the egg mixture both starts and finishes in the oven it would probably be a crust-less quiche.

The benefits of cooking in the oven is the ability to get more even cooking of the eggs to get a more consistent texture throughout.

Answer (score 1):

I've finished an omelette in the oven from the stove. It's nice b/c you don't have to flip it over and you can get just the right amount of cooking you want. I also find that when  an omelette is finished in the oven (that I added a bit of water to) puff up nicer than just on the stove. Don't cook it too much or when you fold it over it will crack.

Comment: I took a guess at the last word you intended. If I guessed wrong, please edit to change it to what you did intend. Welcome to seasoned Advice!

Answer (score -1):

Speed, yes, but cooking in the oven will also cook the omelette more consistently all the way through.

Consider pan frying chicken; the outside cooks much faster than the inside.  It will also possibly dry out the ingredients more than pan frying, making the finished product less runny.

Comment: chicken becomes dry when pan frying usually from being overcooked. An omelette is much more likely to dry out in an oven where it is surrounded by hot, dry air.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying.  It will dry it out more in the oven than pan frying.